# Drop-down get Selected item Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I want to change my button text when my dropdown item is clicked. I am using this code block but I can't do it:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Alan Ekle
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul id="Secenekler" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Isim</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SoyIsim</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Adress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Numara</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yaş</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tanıdık 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And my script. I don't get the `alert()` message.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){           
    alert("tiklandi");

    $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html( $(this).text()  );

    console.log($(this).text());
    console.log($(this).text($(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn')));
});
```

Comment: This works as expected [here](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/dXwWXG). Are you sure the dropdown menu items all exist at the time your `click()` handler is added? Any errors in the console?

Comment: i get nothing in the console

Comment: I'm more worried about the first part. If the `.dropdown-menu li a` elements haven't yet been created when your script is run, they'll never have onclick handlers attached to them. There would be no errors. If that's the case, `$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() { ... })` would solve the problem.

Comment: It is working fine, check this https://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/jbbmbe6j/3/

Answer (score 0):

try this. TESTED : https://jsfiddle.net/wy52thbf/

**Good Luck**

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
          var getText = $(this).text();
          /*console.log(getText);
          console.log($(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.btn'));*/
          $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.btn').text(getText);
        });
      });
```